# What's the best way to use IRC on the mac?

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation, software

Question in the title basically. Not sure what else I can say!

Comment: ‘Best’ according to which criteria? Do you have a list of features that you consider essential or desirable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most popular IRC client on the Mac platform is undoubtedly [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) (free).  It has a sleek interface and is extremely configurable.

You can find others here: http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/irc

[image: Colloquy]

Comment: The included styles aren't great. I recommend a [a nicer looking one](http://john.albin.net/software/introducing-succinct-for-colloquy).

Comment: I think I actually stopped using IRC purely because Colloquy looking so bad. Now I have that theme and I have got rid of some of the useless buttons (seriously, I dont need to change encoding that much) it is a joy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquy is nice, but I think X-Chat has always been much, much better. http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11070/x-chat-azure